# Ubuntu 23.04 to run on Lenovo T61 with 340 NVIDIA driver and NVIDIA QuadroNVS140M

Tags: nvidia, suspend, ppa, thinkpad, 23.04

[Screen copy of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsVQa.png)I own a Lenovo T61 which uses NVIDIA Quatro NVS140M graphics. Was able to run Ubuntu 20.04 while using a PPA -kelebek333 with not many problems. Upgraded to 22.10 then 23.04. System loads pass the log on but hangs with blinking cursor in upper left corner.

The system loads and runs in the Advanced Options mode, with Firefox, LibreOffice and even uI noticed one difference while system was loading in normal mode. It had several red areas mentioning SSSD problems. I did a copy of that screen which I am enclosing and wondered if anyone could suggest a solution to getting Ubuntu 23.04 to run on this lenovoT61. updates working. The Suspend mode does not work.